# Assign _id or Object to mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the schema which refers to another object.

**model/message.js**

```
var moogoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = moogoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
           .
  user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
           .
});

module.exports = moogoose.model('Message', schema);
```

---

Suppose `user` is the object extracted from database.
Should I assign `user._id` or `user` object to `user` property of message model. I have tried both, they yield same result that is `_id` as value of user property.

```
var message = new Message({
      user: user._id,
});
```

or:

```
var message = new Message({
      user: user
});
```

Comment: I usually assign the ` _id` to the reference fields. I have never assigned the model completely to the objectId reference and it works fine for me

Comment: @NoushadPP What happen when we assign object? Does mongo implicitly assign `_id` property of that object?

Comment: you can use [robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) to see how mongodb handles that. It will be stores as `ObjectId("56xsdcblahblahblah")` in the db which maybe you can reference later.

Comment: `$lookup` operator can fetch the referenced document in a query if you want to also. If you are using mongoose you can use `populate()` function for the same

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the schema that I use.

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var config=require('./config'); //configuarations and APIS keys stored in this file
mongoose.connect(config.MONGO_URL, {server:{poolSize:10}});
var Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var users = new mongoose.Schema({
    mobile: { type: String, unique: true },
    hash: String,
    location:{ type:[Number, Number], index:'2d'},
    locName: String,
    created_at: Number,
    image: {type: String, default: 'NONE'},
    role: {type: String, default: 'USER'},
    name: {type: String, default: 'NONE'},
});
exports.users = mongoose.model('users', users);

var comments = new mongoose.Schema({
    uid: { ObjectId, ref: 'users'},
    liked_by: {type: [ObjectId], default: []},
    like_count: {type: Number, default: 0},
    created_at: Number
});

comments.index({spark_id:1, created_at:1});
exports.comments = mongoose.model('comments', comments);
```

This is one of the functions

```
dbase.comments.find({uid: req.body.user._id, function(err, response){
    if(!err){
        //do what you want
    }else{
        //handle error
    }
}).sort({created_at: -1}).skip(count).limit(50).lean();
```